# How to check for HTMLDivElement in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, internet-explorer-7

I have the following code;

```
if(data.constructor == HTMLDivElement)
```

Now IE7 does not have/support HTMLDivElement.

How do I check for the same for IE7.

I tried

```
if(HTMLDivElement != undefined)
```

But it still gives an error on IE7.

Comment: Are you really using jQuery or did you just tag it as jQuery?

Comment: Actually i m using jQuery...but guess for this particular line, it is not getting used...

Comment: If you are using jQuery, I would keep using it. Falling in and out of a framework can cause headaches when reading the code later. A simple `.length` test should work for you.

Comment: Is it to check whether an element is div or not ...? Right

Comment: `.nodeName` for that. Or use a css selecter as below.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(data.constructor === document.createElement('div').constructor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you can use a simpler test.

```
$('div#id').length == 0
```

That would be true when the element did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do it using jQuery's [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

```
var isItDiv = $(data).is('div');
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fetZr/1/):

```
//Using plain DOM elements - no cheating
var e1 = document.getElementById('elem1'); //<div id="elem1">
var e2 = document.getElementById('elem2'); //<button id="elem2">

//it does not even have to be in the DOM!
var ce = document.createElement('div');

console.log($(e1).is('div')); //true
console.log($(e2).is('div')); //false
console.log($(ce).is('div')); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something a kind simple like this:

```
if (data.tagName == 'DIV') {
    // do something
}
```